A family try to fight off the villain in snowed cabin, while the daughter get tricked by one on climax

Nationality of movie : Not sure (most likely American)
Color film 
Era: 8~90's
Thriller, Action, Family movie
Memorable Scene: 

After a long struggle, the family finally managed to tie up a villain(male, 40ish) to the railings of staircase in a cabin on a snowed mountain. The villain tricks the young daughter by asking her a glass of water with very tired appearance. When the daughter approaches him, he grabs her and threatens the family again. Somehow his plan fails, and this time he gets tied up throughly via duct-tape like an Egyptian mummy. But while no one watches over him, he sneaks over to the broken glass shards and cut the tape by squirming over it.

I think the movie is Avalanche (1994)
Summary :

In this made-for-television movie, David Hasselhoff stars as a diamond smuggler who crashes his plane into the snowy mountains. His reckless move sets off an avalanche that traps him, along with a father and his kids. The family must battle to survive both Mother Nature and the criminal-minded Hasselhoff.

Picture from the scenes you remember :
The girl giving water to the villain :

The villain in duct-tape :

The broken glass shard used by the villain to escape :

Links :

IMDB page
Wikipedia page


Hey Thank you so much! this bugged me for ages
